# Adding feedback to chatbot in Bot Composer

Tags: botframework, chatbot

I'm creating a chatbot using Bot Composer and want to add a feedback dialog at the end of the conversation.

I was wondering how this feedback would be triggered? I've taken a look and there is a activities trigger called 'Conversation ended (EndOfConversation activity)' that I've tried out but struggling to get it working. I can't find a lot of information/documentation on the use of this trigger. Could it be used to infer the end of a conversation and then send a feedback dialog?

Has anyone managed to add a feedback dialog triggered by the end of a conversation to their chatbot using Bot Composer?

Answer (score 2):

> I was wondering how this feedback would be triggered?

Where do you want to trigger it? After the entire dialog has been done, or multiple places in multiple dialogs? One feedback for everything or do you need multiple?

> I've taken a look and there is a activities trigger called 'Conversation ended (EndOfConversation activity)' that I've tried out but struggling to get it working. I can't find a lot of information/documentation on the use of this trigger. Could it be used to infer the end of a conversation and then send a feedback dialog?

EndOfConversation happens after everything is done. You won't be able to utilize this to trigger feedback as feedback is part of the conversation and if this event happens, then that is already done.

By default, dialogs automatically end after they complete.
`"autoEndDialog": true,`

You should add an action to the end (or any appropriate location) of your other dialogs to call (`Begin a new dialog`) the feedback dialog . You could keep track of whether certain feedback dialogs had been set and check for that value in your dialog to see if it should run again (if using a prompt, you can utilize the `"alwaysPrompt"` property). There is quite a bit of flexibility and it really depends on your need. But at the simplest scneario; you would make your feedback dialog, and make that the last action in your main dialog.

I hope that helped. If not, please let me know where I can clarify. Feel free to share any code/json/repo if appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That has been really helpful and resolved my issue!